# CloudWatch Event Cron Expression invalid

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch

I try to add a CloudWatch Scheduled Event with the following cron expression:

```
cron(0 1 * * ? *)
```

I want to trigger this event every day at one o'clock.
But I always get the following error:

> There was an error while saving rule dms-unstage-tibia.
>   Details: Parameter ScheduleExpression is not valid.

What is wrong in this cron expression?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, i fixed it by my self. If you create a CloudWatch Scheduled Event directly in CloudWatch, you don't need the "cron()" syntax, only the expression inside. But if you create the event from Lambda, you have to write "cron()". Not very intuitive.